# Can i have a controller for each div on a page via stateprovider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am creating an AngularJs project with the stateProvider and i want to know if it is possible to have a separate controller on a separate div elements, or maybe i am doing something the wrong way.

I have a page with the following contents

```
<html ng-app"myApp">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</html>
```

I have my app file with the stateprovider that looks like this

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider) {

$stateProvider
    .state("home", {url: "/", templateUrl: "partials/top.html", controller:"topController"})

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

}])
```

Is there anyway i can use 1 controller for the top div element, and another controller for the bottom div element?  Do i need an "overall" controller as well?

Simple example would be great, thanks in advance

Comment: You can use nested controllers, as shown in [this example](http://jsbin.com/yafid/2/watch?html,js,output) (taken from the [angularjs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)). Child controllers can redefine scope variables.

Comment: Should i not put the controllers in my .config via stateprovider?

Comment: It really depends on what you need. The answer below gives you an example if you want to separate controllers entirely and divide a page in several views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with "views":

```
.state ('State1', {url: '/state1', views:
    {'viewA': {templateUrl: 'partials/viewA', controller: 'ControllerA'} },
    {'viewB': {templateUrl: 'partials/viewB', controller: 'ControllerB'} }
}
```

Now you can insert each view into your HTML with ui-view ="ViewA" & ui-view="viewB" each with their individual controller.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views